# How to read a column of time from a csv file in R for mathematical operations?

Tags: r, csv, xts

I have a column of time in a csv file in R like this:
column name is: Time

```
Time
3/4/2016 14:43:30
3/4/2016 14:43:33
3/4/2016 14:43:37
```

When I am trying to read this Time I am getting a NULL vector. I want to perform some addition/subtraction calculations on time extracted from this. I am using the following commands:

```
data=read.csv("ABC.csv",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,colClasses=c("Time"="character"))
vector1<-data$Time
```

and vector1 gives me NULL.
Can anyone tell how I should approach this problem and extract times as numeric so that I can perform some calculations.

Comment: Your code doesn't give `NULL` on my system.

Comment: So does it give you all these 3 times in character format?

Comment: Yes, note that I copied your data from the question and used the `text` parameter to pass it to `read.csv`. My guess is that the file is not found (have you set the working directory?), but then you should see an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically time should be converted from character class to POSIX.
you can use `as.POSIXlt` and specify your format.
check [defintion](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.POSIXlt.html) for more information.

note that in your case you get NULL because probably there is no column called Time in your data. please supply repreducible data to more accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

try using strptime

```
data$Time <- strptime(data$Time, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Using this I am getting a vector having all NA